# How can adding an OR conditional to a inner select reduce the number of results using a mongo jdbc driver

Tags: sql, mongodb

If I run the following query through a mongo jdbc driver I get 3 results with my existing data set

```
SELECT a1.ACTIVITY,
       a1.START_TIME,
       a1.END_TIME,
FROM ACTIVITIES a1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ai._ID) 
            AS maxid 
            FROM ACTIVITIES ai
            WHERE ai.activity = 'writing'
            GROUP BY ai.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID) a2 ON (a2.maxid = a1._ID)
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_TASKS pt ON a1.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID = pt._ID
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON a1.ACTOR_ID = u._ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECTS p ON pt.PROJECT_ID = p._ID
```

If I then add `OR ai.activity = 'editing'`to the inner select I only get 1 result. How can adding this OR conditional to the inner select reduce the number of results

```
SELECT a1.ACTIVITY,
       a1.START_TIME,
       a1.END_TIME,
FROM ACTIVITIES a1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ai._ID) 
            AS maxid 
            FROM ACTIVITIES ai
            WHERE ai.activity = 'writing'
            OR ai.activity = 'editing' 
            GROUP BY ai.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID) a2 ON (a2.maxid = a1._ID)
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_TASKS pt ON a1.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID = pt._ID
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON a1.ACTOR_ID = u._ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECTS p ON pt.PROJECT_ID = p._ID
```

Comment: Your OR is affecting the ID returned by MAX. There are 3 matches to that id for the first query, but only 1 for the second.

Comment: Adding rows can also remove rows with left joins (e.g. `WHERE joinFailed`). Not the case here.

Comment: Is the `_ID` unique?

Comment: @dnoeth it should be yes

Comment: If this is your actual query and `_ID` is unique then adding this condition can't decrease the number of rows, there must be something else. What if you simply run the `MAX` standalone?

Comment: @dnoeth The actual query selects a few more fields but besides that it is exactly the same so if you are correct it must be that the _ID isn't unique. The query is actually being run on a mongo JDBC driver and although in mongo the activity _ids are unique I guess it's possible something weird is going on when mongo is being converted to a relational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like the query below in the end which from what I gather does the same thing but slower. I suspect the error I was seeing is due to strange behavior of a mongo JDBC driver I was passing the queries to which converted them to mongo query language. I updated the question to make it more useful.

```
SELECT
  a1.ACTIVITY,
  a1.START_TIME,
  a1.END_TIME,
FROM ACTIVITIES a1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(ai._ID) as maxid
                  FROM ACTIVITIES ai
                  WHERE ai.ACTIVITY = 'writing'
                  GROUP BY ai.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(ai._ID) as maxid
                  FROM ACTIVITIES ai
                  WHERE ai.ACTIVITY = 'editing'
                  GROUP BY ai.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID) as a2
ON (a2.maxid = a1._ID)
LEFT JOIN PROJECT_TASKS pt
  ON a1.ACTIVITY_CONTAINER_ID = pt._ID
LEFT JOIN USERS u
  ON a1.ACTOR_ID = u._ID
LEFT JOIN PROJECTS p
  ON pt.PROJECT_ID = p._ID
```